# AngularJS pagination - id counter start from 1 in new pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have added `ui.bootstrap` pagination, works great.
but the contacts id number starts from the beggining in new pages. I want it to continue increment.

#### View ([plnkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/uiM4VbJrwWf33KeFN9bO?p=preview))

```
<tr ng-repeat="trainee in trainees.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) | filter: search" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
    <td class="hidden-xs">{{$index+1}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.date | date:'d/M/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.grade}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.subject}}</td>
    <td width="180px"><a href="#edit-form"><button type="button" href="#edit-form" class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index" ng-click="editForm($index,trainee)">Edit</button></a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="traineeDetails(trainee)">Details</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

#### For example, first page:

```
id 1: name - rayu, id 2: name - glen
second page: id 1, instead of 3!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  it like in this - [demo fiddle](http://plnkr.co/edit/EvwLSSCdGuEDVhiqazVr?p=preview). It would be much better to calculate this kind of output inside your controller. Also the search does work nicely on the whole object now by adding `startFrom` & `limitTo` filter.

```
<tbody>
  <tr ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}"
      ng-click="setClickedRow($index)"
      ng-repeat="trainee in trainees 
        | filter: search
        | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage
        | limitTo:itemsPerPage">
    <td class="hidden-xs">{{$index+1 + (itemsPerPage * (currentPage-1))}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.date | date:'d/M/yyyy'}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.grade}}</td>
    <td>{{trainee.subject}}</td>
    <td width="180px"><a href="#edit-form"><button type="button" href="#edit-form" class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index" ng-click="editForm($index,trainee)">Edit</button></a>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="traineeDetails(trainee)">Details</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

#### startFrom filter

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you please explane me about the search? its only per page, if the item is in page two, cant find it until i select page two

Comment: @torresito updated. I removed the slicing stuff because you need to search the your hole object.

Answer (score 1):

Why just not display the trainee id?

Updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/uDVSyN44SE96RlXgRHlN?p=preview

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
   <br><br>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Date</th>
         <th>Grade</th>
         <th>Subject</th>
         <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="trainee in trainees.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage), ((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) | filter: search" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
         <td>{{trainee.id}}</td>
         <td>{{trainee.name}}</td>
         <td>{{trainee.date | date:'d/M/yyyy'}}</td>
         <td>{{trainee.grade}}</td>
         <td>{{trainee.subject}}</td>
         <td width="180px"><a href="#edit-form"><button type="button" href="#edit-form" class="btn btn-info" ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index" ng-click="editForm($index,trainee)">Edit</button></a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-disabled="selectedRow !== $index" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ng-click="traineeDetails(trainee)">Details</button>  
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Not a good idea while the unique id order could change like `0, 3, 5`. Depending on where the unique Id is coming from.

Comment: Its a identifier, it should be unique. With a calculated ID based on page and items per page you'll get non unique "ids". And I don't see the goal on having calculated ids.

Comment: You are right but in this case its not what the users want to output. We don't know the application specs so we should focus a solution based on the user input.

Comment: I don't agree with that. I think we should always aim to advice to the best possible answer, and not just blindly guide the user into the quickest/easiest solution (and sometimes, wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Just replace {{$index}} with

{{$index+1 + (FILTER.LIMIT * (CURRENT_PAGE-1))}}

That's all you need to do, no need to add startFrom and Limit